# Static site generator that generates JSON rather than HTML

Tags: json, backbone.js, markdown, jekyll, middleman

I'm a big fan of static site generators like [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/) and [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). Generating a complete blog from flat files and throwing them on Amazon S3 without having to worry about database-related performance and/or security issues feels pretty great.

After spending some time developing web-apps with AngularJS, Ember and Backbone I felt like generating JSON files rather than HTML is at least worth a shot.

I've implemented the idea using Jekyll, Liquid Templates and a shell script but it doesn't feel like more than a proof of concept. Maybe one of you guys came up with the same idea, knows a static site generator better suited for a task like this or has anything else to share?